# Setting up a Share Using Windows ACLs (Samba)

Tags: linux, active-directory, share, acl, samba

i have some trouble with this guide https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_a_Share_Using_Windows_ACLs#Adding_a_Share
I don't understand how i should give a AD group rwx rights because there are not in the normal linux groups.
I did not make a "normal" Linux group with the name "Unix Admins" and i don't think i need too.
I have no idea what i got wrong or i didn't understood right..

Answer (score 1):

As I am not allowed to comment (I don't have a 50 reputation), I will just comment here:
Didn't you read the blue box on the page you linked to that said:

If you use the winbind 'ad' backend on Unix domain members and you add a gidNumber attribute to the Domain Admins group in AD, you will break the mapping in idmap.ldb. Domain Admins is mapped as ID_TYPE_BOTH in idmap.ldb, this is to allow the group to own files in Sysvol on a Samba AD DC. It is suggested you create a new AD group (Unix Admins for instance), give this group a gidNumber attribute and add it to the Administrators group and then, on Unix, use the group wherever you would normally use Domain Admins.

so, create an AD group with samba-tool, giving the group the next free gidNumber and then use this group. If the group isn't displayed by 'getent group <WHAT_EVER_YOU_CALL_THE_GROUP>' , then you do not have everything set up correctly.

If you are still having problems, can I suggest you register for the samba mailing list:
https://lists.samba.org/mailman/listinfo/samba

Then come and talk to me there, I wrote most of the page you linked to.